# Perl Shell Execution

Tags: perl

I'm sure you have all used [Metasploit](http://metasploit.com/).

In Metasploit when the user presses the enter key, or types any command Metasploit executes it, and returns back with a `msf:>`.

I was wondering how I could do this in Perl (pretty much make a Perl shell, which executes commands and returns back with that little identifier).

```
while (1) {
    if (<STDIN> eq defined) {
        print ">>"
    }

    $command = <STDIN>;
    if ($command =~ m/help/) {
        print "Help is on its way";
    } elsif ($command =~ m/exit/) {
        exit (1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Perl's pretty much got all you need for this build-in and there are a _lot_ of modules out there to help.

Comment: I have tried using while(1) around the all the code and make it detect newlines (so it prints >>) but it doesn't seem right, also because the commands wont execute inside this while loop :(

Comment: Then post the (relevant) code you have so that people can help you fix it.

Comment: I am not sure, I understand correctly, but if you want to execute the command just use `system($command);`  or `'$command'` or exec "$command"
please refer to the web for the differences of the three methods...

Comment: What do you think that `if (<STDIN> eq defined)` is supposed to do? And why would any command execute, since you're not executing any of the commands?

Comment: Know if a user has entered something? Well I am aren't I? `if ($command =~ m/help) {` what to do here ->

Comment: *"I'm sure you have all used Metasploit."*  Why on Earth would you assume that?

Comment: I'm sure you're mistaken on that point.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at Term::* modules

[Term::ReadLine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aReadLine)

[Term::Shell](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term%3a%3aShell)

Answer (score 1):

Following David's answer, its time for me to promote [`Zoidberg`](http://p3rl.org/Zoidberg). `Zoidberg` is another Perl shell (like `PSh`) but it is modular, embeddable, and extendable.

1. You can use `Zoidberg::Shell` to build a shell for your application, or
2. you can use the `Zoidberg::Fish` plugin system to build a plugin for your needs which would run inside `Zoidberg` itself. It would most likely define some commands, and possibly a syntax and operation mode. The cannonical example of this is a SQL plugin which allows Zoidberg to recognize SQL statements, and then pass them to a waiting db handle and return results, directly from inside the shell!

As it happens, I am the new maintainer. Zoidberg just had its first release in several years which corrected several bugs that had popped up over the years. So while I am not an expert in it yet, I am probably the closest to being one that exists.

Start your reading about `Zoidberg` at the [`zoiduser`](http://p3rl.org/zoiduser) man page, then read more about plugins at [`zoiddevel`](https://metacpan.org/module/zoiddevel#Plugins).

Comment: Can you do something like `$test="test";echo $test` in Zoidberg?  I haven't figured it out just yet.

Comment: works for me, this is a very strange place to ask questions in any case.

Comment: It appears this is quit unstable at least on Cygwin although thank for the link.

Comment: I have seen strange problems when it comes to the readline implementation in use. You might want to check that out.

Answer (score 0):

There's really something called *[Perl Shell](http://search.cpan.org/dist/psh/doc/pshdevel.pod)* (psh) and its available from the CPAN archive.

I haven't tried it, but the documentation is all there:

```
$ cpan
cpan> install Psh
```

---

## EDIT

I've played with it a bit. I had to change `PS1` so it wouldn't interfere with Psh. Originally, my PS1 was set to:

```
PS1=$(print -n "`logname`@`hostname`:";if [[ "${PWD#$HOME}" != "$PWD" ]] then; print -n "~${PWD#$HOME}"; else; print -n "$PWD";fi;print "\n$ ")
```

But, Psh didn't like it. Instead, if I use the Bash settings, it works great:

```
PS1="\u@\h:\W: PSH> "
```

I also get the following warnings when starting:

```
Using an array as a reference is deprecated at /Library/Perl/5.12/Psh/StrategyBunch.pm line 260.
Using an array as a reference is deprecated at /Library/Perl/5.12/Psh/Strategy/Darwin_apps.pm line 47.
```

But it does start up. I haven't figured out shell history editing, but it does take Perl scripts:

```
david@DaveBook:david: PSH> foreach $foo (<*>) {
> print "$foo\n";
> }
```

Comment: you might want to try the recently-brushed-up Zoidberg instead. See my answer for more ...

Comment: @JoelBerger - Looks interesting. Psh is a bit old. I'll have to give Zoidberg a try.